# React + Django communication

Tags: reactjs, django, csv, frontend, backend

I'm working on a data mining web app, you should be able to upload a csv file, apply an algorithm and get results in the browser and a pdf with information (graphs and models for prediction principally) this is my first time using React and Django, so my question is, how to send the csv file from react to django, handle the data and return it to react?
Thanks!!

I've seen a lot of tutorials, but every tutorial use the sqlite data base and the POST method for store data and I only want to process the data inside the csv, because the files will never be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the csv file upload via a HTTP POST request with the `{"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}` header. After that, you can read the file with some python library that handles datasets like pandas, process everything you want about it and then send it back to the client. After that you can delete your file.

Depending of the time of this operation this request can become really slow, though.

I also think there is probably a cleaner solution where you dont even need to utilize the filesystem, just manipulate the file in-memory that came from the request, but i never tried to do something like that in django.

Comment: Thanks! Ill try it. Another question, how data (in the csv) will be handle is coded in the views.py file, right?

Comment: Yeah, i think writing a custom single api view containing your logic for the operation its the way to go